# Include both headers when converting gt object to dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, gtsummary

I am performing a weighted analysis using the functions `tbl_strata` and `tbl_svysummary` in `gtsummary` package. The reproducible code is below

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)
library(srvyr)

data <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25), 
                       strata = c(10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 20, 10, 20, 30, 30, 10, 30, 30, 20, 10, 20, 20, 20, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 20, 30), 
                       weight = c(10, 8, 17, 15, 9, 10, 25, 8, 8, 13, 17, 24, 12, 15, 3, 12, 16, 17, 24, 12, 3, 2, 8, 14, 4), 
                       popgroup = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                       gender = c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male"),
                       inc_01 = c(1500, 1200, 130, 500, 750, 2000, 10000, 1500, 1050, 400, 360, 490, 250, 400, 2500, 1300, 800, 540, 690, 520, 600, 700, 700, 600, 400), 
                       inc_02 = c(360, 450, 120, 300, 900, 560, 450, 280, 720, 360, 1000, 900, 530, 820, 640, 520, 130, 140, 150, 650, 240, 130, 200, 300, 500)), 
                  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L))


tbl <- data |>
  as_survey_design(strata = strata, weights = weight) %>% 
  tbl_strata(
    strata = gender,
    .tbl_fun = 
      ~ .x %>% 
      tbl_svysummary(
        by = popgroup,
        type = where(is.numeric) ~ "continuous", 
        statistic = list(c(inc_01, inc_02) ~ "{mean} ({mean.std.error})"),
        missing = "no",
        digits = list(c(inc_01, inc_02) ~ c(4, 4)),
        include = c(inc_01, inc_02)
        )
  ) |>
  as.data.frame()
```

The challenge am facing is whereas the gt object has both headers as shown below
[image]

conversion to data frame using `as.data.frame` seems to keep the second column only. Is there a way I can have concatenated column names such as **Female A, N = 89**, **Female B, N = 99**, **Male A, N = 73**, **Male B, N = 45**?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is this tagged w/ `data.table`?

Comment: I believe ```data.table``` could achieve similar goal - recall what I want to achieve is more of data wrangling and not really related to weighted analysis

Answer (score 0):

I have manage to have `magrittr::set_names(paste(c("",  sort(rep(unique(data$gender), 2))), colnames(tbl)))` so that the complete code is

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)
library(srvyr)

data <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25), 
                       strata = c(10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 20, 10, 20, 30, 30, 10, 30, 30, 20, 10, 20, 20, 20, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 20, 30), 
                       weight = c(10, 8, 17, 15, 9, 10, 25, 8, 8, 13, 17, 24, 12, 15, 3, 12, 16, 17, 24, 12, 3, 2, 8, 14, 4), 
                       popgroup = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                       gender = c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male"),
                       inc_01 = c(1500, 1200, 130, 500, 750, 2000, 10000, 1500, 1050, 400, 360, 490, 250, 400, 2500, 1300, 800, 540, 690, 520, 600, 700, 700, 600, 400), 
                       inc_02 = c(360, 450, 120, 300, 900, 560, 450, 280, 720, 360, 1000, 900, 530, 820, 640, 520, 130, 140, 150, 650, 240, 130, 200, 300, 500)), 
                  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L))


tbl <- data |>
  as_survey_design(strata = strata, weights = weight) %>% 
  tbl_strata(
    strata = gender,
    .tbl_fun = 
      ~ .x %>% 
      tbl_svysummary(
        by = popgroup,
        type = where(is.numeric) ~ "continuous", 
        statistic = list(c(inc_01, inc_02) ~ "{mean} ({mean.std.error})"),
        missing = "no",
        digits = list(c(inc_01, inc_02) ~ c(4, 4)),
        include = c(inc_01, inc_02)
        )
  ) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  magrittr::set_names(paste(c("",  sort(rep(unique(data$gender), 2))), colnames(tbl)))
```

Comment: I am wondering whether ```col.names``` can be used in place of  ```magrittr::set_names```

Comment: ITYM `colnames<-`....... (`col.names` is a parameter of some functions but not a function itself)